# PHP mysql update record if there is no existing record

Tags: php, mysql

**EDITed and explain in full details**

I working with a project with this scenario.

Each user has a "UID" which is unique ID.

**They can add their own "item_option_name" and "item_option_value".**

**"item_option_name" is not allowed to be duplicated but "item_option_value" is allowed.**

**database_table**

[image]

**update_mysql**

```
public function update_option($uid,$oid,$item_option_name,$option_value){

    $sql_check="SELECT * FROM options where uid='$uid' and item_option_name='$item_option_name'";

    if($this->conn->row_count($sql_check)==true){
        return false;
    }else{
        $sql = "UPDATE options SET item_option_name='$item_option_name', item_option_value='$option_value' WHERE oid='$oid'";
        $this->conn->update($sql);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**When i submit the form, Update function will work if i change item_option_name to something else. It won't work if item_option_name remain unchanged.**

Example 1. If i want to update **Size**

```
item_option_name=Size_new
item_option_value ="large,extra large"
```

and then submit form. It works fine

Example 2.

```
item_option_name=Size
item_option_value ="large,extra large"
```

**and then submit form. item_option_name remains same. It won't work due to "Size" already exist.**

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: inside your update function write simply: `"UPDATE options SET item_option_name='new_item_option_name',item_option_value='$option_value' WHERE uid='$uid' and item_option_name='$item_option_name'`your update is not working as you set 'item_option_name' by the same value

Comment: Is it worth mentioning normalisation at this point?

Comment: let me guess, you like `find_in_set()` ... which won't use indexes

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu I think i didn't explain well for my question. Please check , i have updated the new content.

Comment: @Strawberry I think i didn't explain well for my question. Please check , i have updated the new content.

Comment: @Drew I think i didn't explain well for my question. Please check , i have updated the new content.

Comment: As per your example 2, you will not able to reach the update query because, "$this->conn->row_count($sql_check)" will return true. so you need to change your update function.

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu yes i know the problem is here.  But in order to fulfill my purpose, I not sure how to modify the coding

Comment: Only write your update query inside your update function: `"UPDATE options SET item_option_name='new_item_option_name',item_option_value='$‌​option_value' WHERE uid='$uid' and item_option_name='$item_option_name'` Update will execute only when match will find